# spring security: BadCredendtials exception not handled by the chain and not returning 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

Good morning,

I was following [this tutorial](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/03/08/securing-rest-api-spring-security/), in order to make spring security works with jwt token.

*** my environment versions***
spring boot : 2.0.1 RELEASE

***Spring security config***

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().configurationSource(request -> getCorsConfiguration())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
            .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable();
}
@Bean
TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
    return filter;
}

@Bean
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setRedirectStrategy((HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) -> {
        // no redirection strategy
    });
    return successHandler;
}

/**
 * Disable Spring boot automatic filter registration.
 */
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
    return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
}
```

***Context:***

Token authentication filter is throwing BadCredentialsException, in case the token does not match expectation.

***Expected behaviour:***

spring  chain will catch this error and return 401 error back to the user.

***Current Behaviour:***

the server crashes with 500 error. the error is not handled by spring security.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a Filter may throw exceptions?

Comment: maybe setting .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(yourcustomauthenticationentrypoint) may help.

Comment: @rustyx : I edited my post, there you ll find the full tutorial i was following. the token throws this badCredentialsException.